# Get image from rss xml

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to fetch data from an rss feed but I am having a hard time in getting the image of a blog content/post. It seems like the `<img>` tag is located inside of a `<content:encoded><![CDATA[...]]></content:encoded>` element.

I'm not quite sure what to do with this. Any help is much appreciated.

it looks like this

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[
<p><img class="class1" title="hello world" src="http://www.mysite.com/images/myPhoto.jpg" alt="" width="550" height="227" /></p>
<p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
]]></content:encoded>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of an RSS feed can be anything. Many blogs simply put HTML in the content so you would have to parse the HTML, which can be different every time.

To parse HTML you could turn it into XHTML and then use XPath to query it for the elements you want to find.

If you need more help here, you' ll need to post the structure of the content (if it is known)

Comment: ive now posted the structure of the content in my original post. can you please provide help if im using:

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BlogNews));
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

Comment: Are you sure the structure of the content of the CData is always the same?